Printer RightToLeft
I have 2 PCs and 1 Printer
First PC has Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit
Second PC has Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit (+Visual Studio 6 Installed)
My Printer is: HP LaserJet P2035 (It directly connected to the first pc and shared with second pc)
My problem is:
The following code can work properly in the second pc but in the first pc it not working!
Printer.RightToLeft = True


What does "not working" mean? What happens?

@StayOnTarget I wanted to write (not working) on the subject but stackoverflow blocked the text !!!

You need to edit the question and describe in more detail what is going wrong.
